# Why do \pagenumbering and \setpagecounter break \cleardoublepage?

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided

It had taken me a few hours to hunt down a bug with my Thesis when I discovered `\cleardoublepage` does not have the correct behaviour for twosided documents. It should force a page following the command to begin on an *odd* page so that when printed for book binding, the inner margin is on the left hand side.

I have sort of identified the cause. In the following **MWE**, two lines make `\cleardoublepage` fail if either of the line is set in the state in the following code.

To remedy this, firstly one must have the first page with an odd number, and secondly one must also remove the `\pagenumbering{roman}` line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,english]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0} %Title page must start from an odd number for \cleardoublepage later to work!?
\centering\Huge Testing \texttt{\textbackslash cleardoublepage}
\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman} %The roman numbering here breaks \cleardoublepage too
\normalsize\lipsum[2-7]\clearpage 
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{I need to begin on an odd page}
\end{document}
```

In my Thesis, I would like my title *page label* to be p.0, then next page starts from roman i, ii, iii... then switch to arabic. I am having no luck getting the chapters to appear as odd pages. I can sort of guess the reason, by switching pagenumbering number system and page number counter arbitrarily, one may turn a even *page label* to an odd and vice versa. However, I see no merit in `\cleardoublepage` checking the oddness of the *page* label, but not the *actual page number* (number of pages as appears in the output, *page label* p. ii may actually be the third page, for example). Any way to fix this?

Comment: LaTeX (by default) does not have any record of the logical page number (ie the number of pages shipped out) it only knows the value of the page counter, `\cleardoublepage` just does `\clearpage` then if the current page is even it does a white line then another `\clearpage` so that the `page` counter is then odd.

Comment: This example works as expected, in my opinion. That is, "what David said."

Comment: If you use the `openright` option to the book class `\chapter` will issue `\cleardoublepage` itself at the right point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, plus `openright` is the default behavior with `book`.

Comment: That is undesirable in my opinion. Currently it means I have no mean of begining the real first page, the TOC, as p.i without manually hacking the pages of the subsquent chapters, while preserving 'open rightness'. Is it not easy to obtain the actual page number then?

Comment: Since it appears that you're using the `book` document class, why not use commands such as `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` -- i.e., *logical* markup instructions -- and let LaTeX do all the work that really belongs "behind the scenes," such as using roman page numbering in the front matter (such as half title page, title page, dedication page, table of contents, foreword) and arabic page numbering in the main matter, issuing `\cleardoublepage` instructions as needed, etc.? The title page, at least in traditional book setups, shouldn't get an explicit page number anyway.

Comment: What is wrong with your example if run as posted (apart from the undefined commands in it) the chapter heading comes on page iii which is odd. What page do you want it to come on???

Comment: You have misunderstood my intentions. If I send my document to a printer, it doesn't matter whether the page label is p.ii or p.iii, in the eyes of the printer and ther pdf file, if I began the title page as label 0, then p.iii is actually an even page with respect to the pdf, and the printer will then bind it to the wrong side. While the goal may sound trivial: I simply don't want the title page to start counting from "1".

Comment: I think a hack is to use ``\addtocounter{page}{-1}\cleardoublepage\stepcounter{page}``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is essentially due to setting the page number to 0 on the first physical page which means that the parity of all pages are out. Essentially none of the `\clear(double)page` commands in your example are having any effect as the page numbering and chapter commands are already issuing those commands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,english]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering\Huge Testing \texttt{\string\cleardoublepage}
\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter

\lipsum[2-7]

\chapter{I need to begin on an odd page}
\end{document}
```

Keeps the parity of the physical page and printed page

```
1  -    Title
2  2    blank before front matter (you could use a thispagestyle if 2 not needed
3  i    front matter
4  ii
5  iii  first chapter
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the trick to make sure the first content page reads p.i is to either trick ``\cleardoublepage`` by changing the page counter and back or insert a blank page

Comment: The code above already makes the first page with content i the blank page is inserted by the cleardouplepage executed by `\frontmatter`. cleardoublepage uses the current page style for its blank page so thenmber 2 appears, if you don't want number use \pagestyle{empty}.  I am not sure what you think is a "trick" The above markup just directly mirrors the document structure, it was setting page counter by hand that was causing the problem.